# Mnesia : ejabberd : Export all tables as SQL queries to a file

Tags: mysql, erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I need to migrate **mnesia to mysql from ejabberd**.

- I have tried many ways from ui : From ui there is a node. On selection of node I will have many options out of which one option is backup. On that page there is a option of `Export all tables as SQL queries to a file: host(0.0.0.0)`,I tried to take sql backup but file is empty
- I also tried these commands:
  `ejabberdctl export2odbc localhost /var/lib/ejabberd/new_file.sql`. This is also a blank file generating no error.:
  `ejabberdctl export2sql localhost /tmp/sql /var/lib/ejabberd/new.sql`. This command does not execute as `export2sql` does not exist.

Is there any other way to take **sql dump from Mnesia**

Version : **ejabberd**  16.01 **mysql** 5.6.xx

Comment: Which version of ejabberd you are using and which sql database do you use?

Comment: Hi @LamteiW : I have udpated the quetion. I am still looking for solution. Is is really possible?

Answer (score 3):

The sql export command was added in 16.04 and named as export_sql and later renamed to export2sql in 16.06. So there's no way to take a dump directly, but you have two alternatives:

- If you can upgrade ejabberd, then its straight forward, upgrade the server, take a dump of the sql.

  - Take a backup of the relevant folders, like database/spool directory, config directory, etc.
  - Upgrade the server to the latest version or at least version 17.07 (the reason being since version 17.06 most of the tables can be exported to sql file, but 17.03-17.06 suffers a [bug](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-17.07/).
  - Configure ejabberd to use mysql as a backend database. 
    Make sure the following modules have the `db_type: sql` option.

    mod_announce, mod_caps, mod_irc, mod_last, mod_muc, mod_offline, mod_privacy, mod_private, mod_pubsub, mod_roster, mod_shared_roster, mod_vcard, mod_vcard_xupdate
  - Restore the spool directory and make sure you have the same permissions
    for all the files and sub-directories as before.
  - Run the ejabberd2sql with hosts and the sql filename as parameters

  **Note**: If you only need the sql dump you might want to revert back the configuration after the dump.
- If you cannot upgrade the server, you can install the latest version of ejabberd in another machine, copy the database directory, follow the same procedure above and you can get the dump of your sql.